# Installing egit on eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, egit, eclipse-indigo

Installing egit on indigo im given following options :

[image]

I've just checked 'Eclipse Egit' but should I be installing the other two unchecked features ? What are they used for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mylyn is the task and application lifecycle management (ALM) framework
>   for Eclipse.
>   http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/
>
> EGit for Mylyn is a custom fork of EGit. It integrates EGit, the Git
>   plugin for Eclipse, with Mylyn, the task-focused framework.
>   http://www.javaforge.com/project/EGIT
>
> The EGit Mylyn GitHub connector supports creating task repositories
>   for working with GitHub issues and Gists
>   http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/GitHub/UserGuide